# Count up timer on multiple activities

Tags: java, android

I have a count up timer in one of my activities and I want to show that timer with elapsed time in my 2nd activity. I tried to Use Fragments for this but the timer keeps restaring on the launch of 2nd activity.

My timer code is:

```
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
    /*  Timer.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));*/
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Comment: Create a service and place the timer into it and show updated result on any activity from service.

Comment: i had that idea but i don't know how to create a background Service. Can u please Share some Code? It would be a big help.

Comment: define - "show a timer".

Comment: what does it mean TheLostMind?

Comment: Can you post the code samples?

Comment: Take a look this example.
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `startTime` from the first activity to the second in the `Intent`. In the second activity, don't set `startTime` to `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` but instead read it from the extras in the `Intent` sent from the first activity.